# How to keep/exclude a particular package path when using proguard?

Tags: android, proguard

I want to exclude some file paths from ProGuard. Example `com.myapp.customcomponents`

How can I do this?  I hate to be placing -keep flags for every single custom component file I have in this directory.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
-keep public class com.myapp.customcomponents.*
```

Answer (score 303, accepted):

You don't specify in what way it doesn't work. Your configuration keeps the names of all public classes in the specified package:

```
-keep public class com.myapp.customcomponents.*
```

The following configuration keeps the names of all public classes in the specified package and its subpackages:

```
-keep public class com.myapp.customcomponents.**
```

The following configuration keeps the names of all public/protected classes/fields/methods in the specified package and its subpackages:

```
-keep public class com.myapp.customcomponents.** {
  public protected *;
}
```

Comment: Double asterisks (**) doesn't compile anymore (Android Studio 4.0)

Comment: Android Studio 4.x will show errors like "Unresolved class name" etc. for double asterisks (**), but it will work as expected.

Comment: Its fixed and will not give errors in the [upcoming releases, check details here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153616200)

Answer (score 88):

Add the following line at the bottom of your ProGuard configuration:

```
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
```

Replace package name accordingly, here the package `com.facebook` will be excluded from ProGuard.

Comment: why keep and dontwarn use together

Comment: @Jongz Puangput, if I right - if app do not use com.facebook package, then on build will be shown note "the configuration refers to the unknown class ...". -dontwarn disable this note.

Comment: what does `{ *; }` means?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar i means every member, method, class in every scope, in short everything!

Answer (score 14):

What worked for me using Android Studio 4.0 is:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.myapp.customcomponents.* {
    <fields>;
    <init>();
    <methods>;
}
```

Double asterisks (**) in other answers did not work for me. I also tried the above configuration with R8, works fine.

Comment: this answer is most up to date answer i think. thank you.

Comment: Thanks @mtsahakis, this is the only answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of people seem to recommend `-keep class com.myapp.customcomponents.** { *; }` as a way to exclude a path from being processed. See here:

1. [exclude packages from proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537003/exclude-packages-from-proguard)
2. [Make Proguard completely ignore package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128266/make-proguard-completely-ignore-package)
3. [Prevent a directory from proguard obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47506682/prevent-a-directory-from-proguard-obfuscation)

The problem with this solution is that there is still some level of obfuscation happening, which can break your code. You can see the mapping in the mapping print out:

```
java.lang.String toString() -> toString
int getMemoizedSerializedSize() -> getMemoizedSerializedSize
void setMemoizedSerializedSize(int) -> setMemoizedSerializedSize
int getSerializedSize() -> getSerializedSize
boolean equals(java.lang.Object) -> equals
int hashCode() -> hashCode
```

The solution I have opted for is a two step process. First, use `injars` with a filter to select the package path I would like to process. It is possible to add the other package pathes as libraries.

```
-injars       artifacts/in.jar(org/toprocess/**.class)
-outjars      out/processed.jar
-libraryjars  artifacts/in.jar(org/skipped/**.class)
-libraryjars  artifacts/in.jar(org/moreskipped/**.class)
```

Second, merge the processed jar with the original jar, but only those paths that were skipped.

```
-injars  out/processed.jar
-injars  artifacts/in.jar(org/skipped/**.class)
-injars  artifacts/in.jar(org/moreskipped/**.class)
-outjars out/merged.jar

-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
```

The result is a merged jar that is the combination of the processed package path and the skipped paths. This exercise is invalid, if someone can provide a way to skip processing of certain paths completely (which I haven't found).

Answer (score 1):

Put all your models-related include `models`, `requests` and `responses` object into a central sub package.

For example: `com.example.models`

Then add this line to your `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.example.models.** { <fields>; }
```

Comment: I have spent too much time solving some issue related to model class in retrofit body parameter.