# How to exclude Facebook project from ProGuard?

Tags: android, facebook, proguard

The Facebook project `com.facebook.*` is library project to the main project. If I compile the APK with ProGuard default file `proguard-android.txt`, then it messes something in the Facebook project and some features do not work as planned.

How can I exclude the whole FB project from ProGuard?

Comment: Not really sure about FB, but for ActionBarSherlock it is stated as following on the website: Add the following lines:

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation* 

I assume you can adjust some names and you're good to go with this.

Comment: Just check this post :
[How to keep/exclude a particular package path when using proguard?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830474/how-to-keep-exclude-a-particular-package-path-when-using-proguard

Comment: @EvZ Thanks. Someone even posted the path for Facebook library project.