# exclude packages from proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard, obfuscation

How can I inlcude some of the packages after I excluded the parent package in proguard.cfg:

Ex:

-keep com.myapp.** { *; }

I want proguard to obfuscate com.myapp.data.** { *; }

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use ProGuard-style regular expressions for the class name:

```
-keep class !com.myapp.data.**,com.myapp.** { *; }
```

Comment: I tried -keep class com.myapp.** { *; } -keep class !com.myapp.data.** { *; } and it didn't work?!?!

Comment: Each -keep option is considered independently, so that's different.

Comment: Although I still don't understand why I should put them in one line, it worked and thank you :)

Comment: If I also want to include enum, what should I do?