# How to exclude a particular package from obfuscation?

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I am using proguard for obfuscating  for jar. The jar has three packages (SAY A,B,C). I want a particular package to be excluded from obfuscating (a) How can we achieve this?

How to write the config file for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to keep/exclude a particular package path when using proguard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830474/how-to-keep-exclude-a-particular-package-path-when-using-proguard)

Comment: I want to exclude the whole package A itself, and the package B imports classes from package A.

Comment: Have you tried reading the Proguard documentation?  For example, this section: http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#classspecification ???