# Make Proguard completely ignore package

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Is it possible to have Proguard enabled but keep some classes completely untouched by Proguard? I have the following lines in my proguard config file:

```
-keep class com.heyzap.** { *; }
```

But as I can see classes inside Heyzap package are actually changed anyway after Proguard pass (they are different from what I originally had in Heyzap jar file).

I don't know what exactly Proguard do with Heyzap SDK but after this build process fails on converting jar file to dex format with error:

```
EXCEPTION FROM SIMULATION: com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstInterfaceMethodRef cannot be cast to com.android.dx.rop.cst.CstMethodRef
```

Also I have *-dontoptimize* option enabled in my config.

Heyzap recommends to use this line to keep their SDK untouched:

```
-libraryjars libs/heyzap-ads-sdk.jar
```

But Android Studio fails to compile the project with this line added because *heyzap-ads-sdk.jar* is automatically added to *-injars* list (it throws '*The same input jar is specified twice.*' error).

Answer (score 1):

To make ProGuard completely ignore a package you can use:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class com.my.package.** {*;}
```

But, the error you're getting means something else, you should try to remove **-libraryjars libs/heyzap-ads-sdk.jar** from your ProGuard file, because this library is probably being added somewhere else like in your **build.gradle** file, probably by this line:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

Comment: I tried 'keepclasseswithmembers' but my classes were still modified. Yes, sure I can't use 'libraryjars' option because the Heyzap jar is added from my build.gradle. But I need to keep proguard away from it, like it would be with 'libraryjars'.