# How to exclude package name and sub package name while using progaurd In Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-r8

I have my project package name as

```
in.myapplication.app
```

and I have a package which contains several packages as well like this

```
in.myapplication.app.samplePackage

in.myapplication.app.samplePackage.SubPackage
```

Now I want to exclude all the classes present inside `samplePackage` package including subpackage classes also. I tried this keep rule inside progaurd file

```
-keep class  in.myapplication.app.samplePackage.*{*;}
```

But it only allows the classes that are in `samplePackage` and not in `samplePackage.SubPackage`

I have checked similar questions

1. [How to keep/exclude a particular package path when using proguard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4830474/9365212)
2. [Make Proguard completely ignore package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128266/make-proguard-completely-ignore-package)

Nothing working and tried to use these

```
-keep class in.myapplication.app.samplePackage.** {*;}
```

But it's showing me a warning

> Unresolved reference name in shrinker config file

So, How to exclude package name and sub package name while using progaurd In Android Studio?

Comment: This works for me -keep class in.myapplication.app.samplePackage.** { *; }

Comment: @Style-7 which android version are you using? I am using android studio 4.0 I presume that it exists on 4.0 and above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On **Android Studio 4.0** and above **double asterisks (**)** won't compile anymore. So if you want to fix this error and exclude sub-packages do it like this

```
-keep class in.myapplication.app.samplePackage.*.* {*;}
```

this will exclude the packages inside `samplePackage` as well

Comment: The issue in Android Studio 4.0 is in the IDE which wrongly flags the `**` syntax. It still works with the actual R8 compilation, so I suggest to keep using it, as the semantics is not the same as e.g. `*.*`. See [issue 153616200](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/153616200).

Comment: @sgjesse  So it's the IDE problem then?

Comment: Yes the IDE will make a class like `com.example.**` with "Unresolved class name", but the R8 compiler will process it just fine. Please follow the referenced bug for progress on fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

The correct rule for keeping everything in package `in.myapplication.app.samplePackage` and all subpackages is:

```
-keep class in.myapplication.app.samplePackage.** {*;}
```

The warning you see could be a false negative, see [issue 153616200](http://issuetracker.google.com/153616200).

Comment: See Daniel's comment on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4904402/9365212 I am experiencing same thing