# ProtocolException: Too many follow-up requests: 21 with Proguard and OkHttp 3.0 in Android

Tags: android, proguard, retrofit2, android-proguard, okhttp

I am creating an app using Retrofit 2.1.0 and OkHttp 3.4.2.

In debug mode with minifyEnabled set to false everything works perfectly but as soon as i change minifyEnabled to true i get the following exception:

```
HTTP FAILED: java.net.ProtocolException: Too many follow-up requests: 21
```

My Proguard rules for OkHttp are as follows:

```
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp3.** {
    *;
}
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
```

I can't understand why this exception is thrown and i do not understand why the app is seems to be making 21 follow up requests. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6):

I've just had this exact same error: `java.net.ProtocolException: Too many follow-up requests: 21`. For your interest I'm using Retrofit 2.5.0 and OkHttp 3.14.1, although versions don't matter much.

I too **only have this error with Proguard enabled** (actually I'm using R8 but the result is the same). This is important and hints the root cause.

What's the problem? I authenticate using OAuth, adding an "Authorization" header as usual. When the token expires the server sends a 401 Unauthorized. Since I'm using an OkHttp [`Authenticator`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Authenticator.html) to refresh the token, when a 401 is received the [`authenticate`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/Authenticator.html#authenticate-okhttp3.Route-okhttp3.Response-) method is called.

The problem is that I parse the response of this 401 Unauthorized request using Gson, like this:

```
override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
    val responseError: ResponseError? = response.body()?.let {
        Gson().fromJson(it.string(), ResponseError::class.java) // <- Fails!
    }
    // Check server response and decide if should refresh token...
}
```

But *since the class `ResponseError` is obfuscated by proguard it's fields don't match the names of the JSON that the server sends, which makes `Gson().fromJson` fail*, and consequently the token is not refreshed. The result is that a network call is performed repeatedly until the Exception is thrown.

The fix is trivial. Just add `@Keep` to `ResponseError`:

```
import androidx.annotation.Keep

@Keep
data class ResponseError(
    val error: String? = null,
    val error_description: String? = null
)
```

---

Since your problem happens with proguard enabled only, it's likely that a request or response class is being obfuscated, which makes the JSON parsing fail. Or you may be saving some JSON to Shared Preferences using `Gson.fromJson` and `Gson.fromJson` with an obfuscated class.

To fix the problem add `@SerializedName` and/or `@Keep` to all your requests and responses (specially enums, which give more trouble). Alternatively you can simply put the all the requests and responses into a single package and [exclude it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4830474/4034572). In addition to requests and responses, pay special attention to any `Gson.fromJson` and `Gson.fromJson` call too.

To help diagnose the problem you can check what proguard/R8 does by checking the mappings file you'll find in `app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt` (for a release build). It contains all the transformations that proguard/R8 has done to your code.

You can also analyze the APK by doing Build -> Analyze APK... You'll see which classes are being obfuscated in a very simple way. You can analyze 2 APKs at the same time (one minified and one not minified) and compare them.