# How to protect classes from being removed by MINIFY_ENABLED?

Tags: android, proguard, minify

I am using FirebaseFirestore in my project. When i am in debug mode, minifyEnabled FALSE, the app runs just fine, but when I build a signed .apk, minifyEnabled TRUE, it doesn't work as I expect. i.e it doesn't load data from firebase Firestore.

**What KEEP statments should i write to exlude FIREBASE FIRESTORE and Glide classes from minifying ?**

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Problem will be with your release ProGuard configuration. Post it here.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830474/how-to-keep-exclude-a-particular-package-path-when-using-proguard

Comment: @Tomas, where  can i find the release ProGuard configurations ?

Comment: @Nasib If you need to know basics, then look here: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Configuring-ProGuard

Comment: @Tomas, thank you

my Proguard configuration is

`buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled false

            shrinkResources false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),

                    'proguard-rules.pro'

        }

    }`

Comment: @Nasib now copy here content of your 'proguard-rules.pro' file. And edit your question.

Comment: @TomasIvan i've edited my question. there's the contents of 'proguard-rules.pro' please check it

Comment: basics: https://github.com/bumptech/glide#proguard and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start#proguard

Comment: Everytime you use some 3rd party library and use proguard, then take a look at project websites and look for proguard rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
the ProGuard renames almost every class. And it renamed my model class (pojo), that which i used for encapsulating data for the Firestore, and firestore only recognized that name, in my  case, "Upload".

but when the proguard renamed it, it named the "Upload" class as " j "
and, the firestore SDK didn't recognize "j".

*that was the problem.*

i added
"`@Keep`"   annotation with "Upload" class and my problem was solved.

```
@Keep
public class Upload{
.....
.....
}
```

**Suggestion:**
You should also add this `@Keep` annotation for [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) Entity Classes and [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) data Classes