# App Crashes in release but works fine in Debug mode

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-play

I have app uploaded on Play Store. It works **fine in Debug mode** but when I download same APK (Release mode) from play store, it gets crashed. I am unable to figure out and Stack Trace is not giving exact error location.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: 
>     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:318)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:354)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:223)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:242)
>     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:243)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
>     at com.biocare.fots.HomeActivity$GetEmpDetailsTask.doInBackground (HomeActivity.java)
>     or                     .onPostExecute (HomeActivity.java)
>     at com.biocare.fots.HomeActivity$GetEmpDetailsTask.doInBackground (HomeActivity.java)
>     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:304)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
>     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:243)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:761)

Above stack trace is copied from Play Store Developer Console. Same error is shown in Firebase console.

[image]

Here is my AsyncTask Code:

```
 private static class GetEmpDetailsTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    WeakReference<HomeActivity> mContext;

    GetEmpDetailsTask(HomeActivity context) {
        mContext = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        if(android.os.Debug.isDebuggerConnected())
            android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
        AppDatabase appDatabase = AppDatabase.getAppDatabaseInstance(
                mContext.get());
        Employee employee = appDatabase.employeeDAO().get();
        FotApplication.Employee.Id = employee.employeeId;
        FotApplication.Employee.Name = employee.firstName + " "
                + employee.lastName;
        FotApplication.Employee.Designation = employee.empDesignationName;
        FotApplication.Employee.DesignationDesc = employee.empDesignationName;
        FotApplication.Employee.Email = employee.email;
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        mContext.get().mTvEmpName.setText(FotApplication.Employee.Name);
        mContext.get().mTvEmpEmail.setText(FotApplication.Employee.Email);
    }
}
```

And here is my **build.gradle (Module: app)**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'abc'
            keyPassword 'test'
            storeFile file('path/to/keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'testpass'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.fats"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 38
        versionName "2.1.9"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation ('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
```

**EDIT 1:**

Logcat from Android Studio:

```
 Process: com.biocare.fots, PID: 15978
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.biocare.database.n.b' on a null object reference
    at com.biocare.fots.HomeActivity$a.a(Unknown Source:20)
    at com.biocare.fots.HomeActivity$a.doInBackground(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, that if your DAO (f.e. Room) uses reflection, when you build release apk with `minifyEnable=true`, your DAO can't find something. Try to check your proguard.

UPD
Yes, you have problem with obfuscation. `'java.lang.String com.biocare.database.n.b'` this `'n.b'` means that you had right path before obfuscation, but after obfuscation path was changed to values 'n' and 'b'. You should add this files (I don't know certain files, because I don't know your code) in proguard exclude list.

You can read more in proguard documentation. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830474/how-to-keep-exclude-a-particular-package-path-when-using-proguard) can be useful too

Comment: How to check proguard?

Comment: I don't know, what exactly your should check. You can turn off minify in release flavour and build it. If you don't get crash, so you have problem with obfuscation and you need to change proguard. How to work with this, you can read in documentation. Otherwise, you deal with another problem (with null context f.e). In this case you can put 'assertion' to probably crash places.

Comment: I have added log from Android Studio when live app crashes. Please look at this. It may be helpful to diagnose the issue.

Comment: You are pointing in the right direction. Where should I add **exclude list** in proguard rule?  Like this `-keep public class com.myapp.customcomponents.*`? Should I add it at the end of the **Module: app** file?

Comment: You have proguard-rules.pro file in app folder of your project. You can put lines above here

Answer (score 0):

Please set debuggable = true to find root cause.
I think from your proguard ~

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34827119)