# How to prevent proguard to shrink module library ? JAR

Tags: android, module, proguard, android-library, video-compression

I have fishwjy videocompressor library that i import to my project, Everything is Okay when i run the code to compressing video in debug mode, but i get error when i run video compressing after building apk in release mode, is this problem from proguard? and how could i solve this problem?, and how i keep the module from proguard?

my build.gradle

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

my proguard-rules

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /Android/AndroidSdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keep class com.woxthebox.draglistview.** { *; }
-keep class com.vincent.videocompressor.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers com.vincent.videocompressor.** { *; }
-keep class videocompressor.**
-keepclassmembers videocompressor.**

-keep public class com.vincent.videocompressor.** {
  public protected *;
}
-keep public class videocompressor.** {
  public protected *;
}
```

This is the error, i got in release mode

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/aspectj/runtime/reflect/Factory;
    at com.coremedia.iso.boxes.FileTypeBox.ajc$preClinit(FileTypeBox.java:1)
    at com.coremedia.iso.boxes.FileTypeBox.<clinit>(FileTypeBox.java:1)
    at com.vincent.videocompressor.MP4Builder.createFileTypeBox(MP4Builder.java:155)
    at com.vincent.videocompressor.MP4Builder.createMovie(MP4Builder.java:62)
    at com.vincent.videocompressor.VideoController.convertVideo(VideoController.java:341)
    at com.vincent.videocompressor.VideoCompress$VideoCompressTask.doInBackground(VideoCompress.java:51)
    at com.vincent.videocompressor.VideoCompress$VideoCompressTask.doInBackground(VideoCompress.java:32)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.Factory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.myapps.myapps-rN2AAoto-QpoZhVaUg_EFQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapps.myapps-rN2AAoto-QpoZhVaUg_EFQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: show your proguard file

Comment: Have a look at this, you can keep all the public packages of a specific library with specifying the package name:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830474/how-to-keep-exclude-a-particular-package-path-when-using-proguard

Comment: @Sagargujarati, ive added

Answer (score 1):

use -dontshrink

from the proguard [manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage#dontshrink)

> -dontshrink Specifies not to shrink the input. By default, ProGuard shrinks the code: it removes all unused classes and class members. It
>   only keeps the ones listed by the various -keep options, and the ones
>   on which they depend, directly or indirectly. It also applies a
>   shrinking step after each optimization step, since some optimizations
>   may open up the possibility to remove more classes and class members.